# Use class methods within Elasticsearch-Model's `mapping do`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails, elasticsearch-model

I'm generating a rather complex mapping using `Elasticsearch-Model`. I extracted all the search related methods into an `ActiveSupport::Concern`. The following code was written while using the Tire gem, but I'm upgrading the gem to Elasticsearch-Rails and Elasticsearch-Model, since Tire doesn't support Elasticsearch 1.x .
The current implementation looks like this:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module SearchBooks
extend ActiveSupport::Concern

included do
   include Elasticsearch::Model
   include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

   mapping do
      locales = %w['de', 'en', 'fr']
         locales.each do |locale|
            class_eval <<-RUBY
               indexes: ... 
            RUBY
      end
   end
 end
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
/Users/xxx/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p647/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/singleton_class.rb:11:in `class_eval': undefined method `indexes' for #<Class:0x007fea661037ec> (NoMethodError)
```

I tried a lot of stuff, e.g. usind `def included(base)` and then `base.eval`, but I can't get `class_eval` under the right scope.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The resolution turned out to be very simple:

Just use `instance_eval` instead of `class_eval`, since the mapping block scopes everything inside to an instance of `Elasticsearch::Model::Indexing::Mappings`.